# What may be the consequences of AC frequency variations on powerline network adapters

Tags: frequency, power-line-communication, power-grid

There has been [several](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/360328/serbia-kosovo-power-grid-row-delays-european-clocks-why) [reports](https://arstechnica.com/tech-policy/2018/03/ovens-across-europe-display-the-wrong-time-due-to-a-serbia-kosovo-grid-dispute/) lately of variations of the main frequency of AC current in European households. What do you think could be the consequences on network signal when using network over powerline (homeplugs)?

Answer (score 1):

Irrelevant.

Those systems do not care about the 50Hz at all. They work on much higher frequencies.